# Rails 3 cache misses on activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

I'm encountering a situation where every request to a cached ActiveRecord object causes a cache miss. I am attempting to cache the permission structure of the current user:

```
my_permissions = Rails.cache.fetch("#{self.id}.permissions") do      
  self.permissions.all
end
```

I find that every page request is querying the db for my permissions. If I change the code to something arbitrary

```
my_permissions = Rails.cache.fetch("#{self.id}.permissions") do      
  "I have no permissions"
end
```

This will correctly live in the cache. I can prove this because if I change the arbitrary line back to my ActiveRecord call, it will keep erroring out due to the cache object being wrong. I have also checked the cache file created and it is correctly being stored as both values, I can see what looks like my permission object, yet it continues to hit the database and not the cache. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Jerremy    Any update on this ??